# 3 divs with overflow scroll wont fit in page max-height 100%

Tags: css

```
body,html{
  max-height:100vh;
}
#content{
  max-height:100%;
}


#div1,#div2,#div3{
  background:#fff;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  max-height: 30%;
}
```

I'm having hard time to make it work.
For example "title2" should be overflow scroll but instead it keeps overflowing its parent. Wont fit in page max-height 100%.

https://jsfiddle.net/cbjkc4dg/1/

Comment: you have to give your #div2 fixed height then it can be scrolling.
see my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cbjkc4dg/2/

Comment: @Anami That would be best as an answer, if you include your code from the fiddle.

Comment: kk, I open an answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

hope i got this right.
made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/1k2qb64a/)

just replace `max-height:30%` with `max-height:33vh`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `overflow: scroll` cannot work if the height is set as a percentage, as you have. A solution is to use `vh` units instead, which work in a very similar way to `%` when it comes to sizing.

Here is a good article on what `vh` is

http://thenewcode.com/660/Using-vw-and-vh-Measurements-In-Modern-Site-Design

Here's a snippet to demonstrate:

```css
body,
html {
  max-height: 100vh;
}
#content {
  max-height: 100%;
}
#div1,
#div2,
#div3 {
  background: #fff;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 30vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h2>
title1
</h2>
  <div id="div1">
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
  </div>
  <h2>
title2
</h2>
  <div id="div2">
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
  </div>
  <h2>
title3
</h2>
  <div id="div3">
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
    <div>row</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this, i hope this works for you, here is a `fiddle` `https://jsfiddle.net/cbjkc4dg/4/`

wrap each block with a `div` like this

```
 <div class="block">
   <h2>title1</h2>
   <div id="div1">
     <div>row</div>
     <div>row</div>
     <div>row</div>
     <div>row</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

and for styles you can make `100vh` for the main parent block so it's parent will also be flexible with it. like here

```
body,
html {
 overflow: hidden;
}

#content {
 height: 100vh;
}

.block {
 height: calc(100vh / 3);
 overflow: hidden;
}

#div1,
#div2,
#div3 {
 background: #fff;
 overflow-y: scroll;
  height: calc(100% - 37px);
}
```